# How do I get a DLL or EXE name from a C# project file?

Tags: c#

I have the path to a C# project file. Using just the raw project file (and knowing if I want Debug or Release), how do I determine the full path to the resulting DLL or EXE?

Comment: You'd have to go through the .csproj file, read the MSBuild schema

Comment: Do you want to find it at run time or design time?

Comment: Do you mean getting the directory of the compiled .exe or dll?

Comment: Inside VS2010 in post-build events section I am using this line with signtool: $(ProjectDir)obj/Release/[YourOutputFile].exe, it points to the resulted project executable file at obj dir. Regards,

Comment: @chris_techno25 No, I mean the full path to the compiled exe or dll.

Comment: @p.s.w.g You're question doesn't make any sense. Obviously my program is running, otherwise it wouldn't make any sense to say I have the path to a C# project file. At the same time, from that project file's perspective we are definitely in design time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that this is not the ideal way to do this because the output path can be easily overriden (particularly when built using CI tools).  If this is not a concern, then you can achieve this by parsing the following:

1. **OutputPath** -- this is relative to the location of the .csproj file
2. **OutputType** -- this will give you the project type and you can derive the file extension
3. **AssemblyName** -- this is the file name of the binary

See [MSBuild common project properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629394.aspx) for details.

However, this part is relatively easy.  The much more difficult part is resolving which `PropertyGroup` section is applicable based on the specified `Condition`.  By default, the `Configuration` and `Platform` are the two input properties used to resolve the applicable `PropertyGroup`.  However, if the project files are customized in any way (not recommended), then your task becomes very, very complicated because you now have to parse ***and evaluate*** `PropertyGroup` conditions.

**Update**: a more robust solution would be to use the MSBuild libraries directly to interpret the project file.  I'm fairly certain this is not that difficult -- I'll post later if I can come up with a working solution.

Comment: Thanks. Worse case scenario, I can cheat and offer a drop-down list of the possible property groups.

Answer (score 1):

The project file is essentially just an XML file with a bunch of options and settings stored in it. To add to the accepted answer here is a small snapshot of a project file so you can see the hierarchy of some of the elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>9.0.21022</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{28819998-A463-46E9-8ADC-855B0DF9AE9C}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>Final_Lab</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Final Lab</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <FileUpgradeFlags>
    </FileUpgradeFlags>
    <UpgradeBackupLocation>
    </UpgradeBackupLocation>
    <OldToolsVersion>3.5</OldToolsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```